# How to define Traingular membership function for fuzzy controller design?

Tags: matlab, controller, simulink, fuzzy-logic, control-theory

I am designing a fuzzy controller and for that, I have to define 3 triangular function sets. They are:

```
1 large
2 medium
3 small
```

But my problem is I have following data only:

```
Maximum input = 3  Minimum input= 0.1

Maximum output = 5.5  Minimum output= 0.8
```

How to define 3 triangular set range based on only this given information?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula for a triangular membership function

```
f=0 if x<=a
f=(x-a)/(b-a) if a<=x<=b
f=(c-x)/(c-b) if b<=x<=c
f=0 if x>c

where a is the min, c is the max and b is the midpoint.
```

In your case, take the top situation where the max is `3` and the min is `0.1`. The midpoint is `(3+0.1)/2=1.55`, so you have

```
f=0 if x<=0.1
f=(x-0)/(1.55-1) if 0.1<=x<=1.55
f=(3-x)/(3-1.55) if 1.55<=x<=3
f=0 if x>3
```

You should be able to take the 2nd example from here, but if not let me know. Something worth pointing out is that the midpoint may not be the ideal `b` in your situation. Any point between `a` and `c` could serve as your `b`, just know that it is the point where the membership function equals `1`.

It is difficult to tell, but it looks like maybe you just have given parameters for two of the functions, perhaps for small and large or medium and large. You may need to use some judgement for the 3rd membership function.